# How to merge two collection in mongoose imported as CSV files?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I came up with following to merge the two collections and would run it once after mongoimport. After this step, there is a node.js app (API) using only the combined "list" collection, with the added Media array field.
 Is there a cleaner solution?  
Is there a way to join them using population and how would the schema look like?

**Following use case:**

- A windows base app outputs two CSV files (every night, overwrites existing)
- Auto import via scheduled .bat file after

```
mongoimport -d products -c list --type csv --file list.csv --headerline --drop
mongoimport -d products -c media --type csv --file media.csv --headerline --drop
```

**Document fields for list collection**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("22fa69t3cac4567dd05dd134"), 
  "Type": "Centrifuge",
   "Model": "XL-12",
   "Price":123000, 
  "SourceKey": NumberLong(85703549)
   … bunch of more fields 
}  
… up to 1000 documents
```

**Document fields for media collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa69f1cac4246dd05dd146"),
    "MediaURL" : "http://media.random.org/media4/0F84881B-4B4B-4793-B2A2-7CB1237B35A1.jpg",
    "ClassSourceKey" : NumberLong(85703549) 
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa69f1cac4246dd05dd158"),
    "MediaURL" : "http://media.random.org/media4/5D16660E-4FAF-4CC6-9AA5-8DFF5B1EA9EE.jpg",
     "ClassSourceKey" : NumberLong(85703549) 
},{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa69f1cac4246dd05dd159"),
    "MediaURL" : "http://media.random.org/media12/CD8B1BFB-7807-4520-975B-8F059ABD379B.jpg",
    "ClassSourceKey" : NumberLong(85703549)
 },
 … up to a 100 documents for each product.
```

SourceKey associates with ClassSourceKey

```
list
    .find({},
    {
        DateListingContract: true,
        StreetNumber: true,
        StreetName: true,
        City: true,
        State: true,
        PostalCode: true,
        ListPrice: true,
        Type: true,
        Model: true,
        SquareFootageStructure: true,
        SourceKey: true
    })
    .sort({ListPrice: -1})
    .exec(function (err, products) {
        if (err) throw err;
        async.eachSeries(products, function(item,callback){
            media.find({ ClassSourceKey : item.SourceKey }, function(err, images){
                if(images.length) {
                    list.update({_id: item.id}, {Media: images}, function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                } else {
                    list.remove({_id: item.id}, function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                }
                callback();
            }, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to use `$set` in order not overwrite the existing document. You can also speed this up wth `.eachLimit()` as there seems to be no problem in running several updates and queries in parallel. Your main restriction is the "multiple associations" cannot be already made present within the CSV content. I presume you have no control over how that is generated.

Comment: Thanks Neil, overwriting the data would be ok since the nightly CSV presents a data set form a certain time to today, so I am only interested in the latest data. I wish to control the CSV better.